# The .dae model loaded with Dx11 assimp looks strange

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine, game-development, assimp

(The Pictures are at bottom)

I am currently using assimp in my DX11 engine to load models, but I am facing difficulty in concatenating two models together.

I am recreating Super Mario Odyssey for my study, and I used the Toolbox Extractor to extract .dae files from mariobody, handL, handR, and head.szs files. Then, I used assimp to read these .dae files.

When I load each model separately, they appear correctly. However, I encounter issues when trying to attach the hands and head to the body.

When connecting the models, I accumulate the matrices from the root node to the connecting node, and if there is a parent model, I link the model accordingly.

```
void Model::recursiveProcessBoneMatrix(aiMatrix4x4 matrix, const std::wstring& nodeName)
{
    const ModelNode* modelNode = FindNode(nodeName);
    aiMatrix4x4 transform = modelNode->mTransformation;

    if (mParentModel)
    {
        // Code written to search for nodes with the same name in the model.
        ModelNode* parentModelNode = mParentModel->FindNode(nodeName);
        if (parentModelNode)
        {
            /*
            Set my hierarchy information based on the parent's corresponding node hierarchy.
            Although the model is forced to move to the position of that node, 
            it causes rotation issues.
            */
            Bone* bone = mParentModel->FindBone(nodeName);

            if (bone != nullptr)
            {
                bone = mParentModel->GetBone(bone->mIndex);

                matrix = bone->mLocalMatrix;
            }
        }
    }

    matrix = matrix * transform;


    if (mBoneMap.find(nodeName) != mBoneMap.end())
    {
        Bone* bone = &mBoneMap.find(nodeName)->second;
        aiMatrix4x4 glovalInvers = FindNode(L"Scene")->GetTransformation();

        // bone->mOffsetMatrix - vectex to bonespace (like world, view, projection transform)
        //matrix - transformed martrix from root
        bone->mFinalMatrix = glovalInvers.Inverse() * matrix * bone->mOffsetMatrix;
        bone->mLocalMatrix = matrix;

        mBones[bone->mIndex].mFinalMatrix = bone->mFinalMatrix;
        mBones[bone->mIndex].mLocalMatrix = matrix;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < modelNode->mChilds.size(); ++i)
    {
        recursiveProcessBoneMatrix(matrix, modelNode->mChilds[i]->mName);
    }
}
```

Based on the fact that it opens correctly in Blender and the extractor, I don't think there's anything wrong with the .dae file.

However, I also suspect that there might be issues with the model itself. So, I will attach the model files to the corresponding Google Drive just in case.
[google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gl6LV-4rlHUwJoTULTZQrLF5_KjkdYVp?usp=sharing)

If you need any other code, feel free to let me know at any time.

[image: Model Loaded by my dx11 engine (using assimp Loader)]
[image: Model Loaded by Toolbox(nintendo game extractor)]